# Where do I enter the Windows Server 2008 key after installing it?

Tags: windows-server-2008

When I installed Windows Server 2008 I didn't have the (activation) key. Now that I have it I can't find where to enter it. Anybody know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Control Panel\System and then under Windows Activation click "Change Product Key".

Answer (score 0):

I know in Vista this is done from the system control panel. I would check there in Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an icon down in the tray, or it will prompt you during logon.  I don't recall how long it will take to prompt you, or if it takes any time at all.

Try rebooting and logging on.

Answer (score 0):

open command window.

type slui 4

follow wizard

Answer (score 0):

Right click on **Computer** and select **Properties**. Then select **Change product key** under the *Windows activation* section.